# Move to SD compatibility

Tags: java, android, xml

I have an application for Android 2.1 and a I'd like to add move-to-sd support for devices with Android 2.2+.

I added that code:

```
<manifest
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.example2"
android:versionName="1.0"
android:versionCode="1"
android:installLocation="auto">
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="7"
    android:targetSdkVersion="8" />
```

But if I keep my project over the sdk level 7. I have an compile error

```
error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'installLocation' in package 'android'    AndroidManifest.xml /example2   line 2  Android AAPT Problem
```

And if I set it to level 8, it is possible that later when programming I introduce some code only available for sdk level 8+ and don't detect it.

Is there some way to fix that? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Eclipse, you should be able to set the target SDK version through the Eclipse UI and it will recognize the `installLocation` attribute.

Project > Properties > Android > Project Build Target

As far as introducing code that only works in api level 8+ but setting a lower min SDK value, everything I've read online says only that there's no way to automatically protect yourself so at this point you just have to be more defensive and mindful with your code.  You need to know which code requires an api level greater than your app's minimum and use Build.VERSION.SDK_INT against the Build.VERSION_CODES enum to check if it's ok to run that code and provide an optional approach if not.

Answer (score 0):

**-Edit-**

Android 2.1 doesn't allow apps to be installed to sd card. For APIs, one would have to target newer versions, but since there is an attribute in the manifest that is recognized by 2.2 and beyond, and ignored by 2.1 and previous versions, this issue can be dealt with through that attribute. (Read comments in this question please. I was wrong before).

Comment: I've got an app that runs on all SDK levels that adds contacts. It uses the ContactsContract API and the Contacts API, depending on what level SDK is used. I imagine something similar could be done so 2.1 doesn't hit any code that it can't use.

Comment: Yes, but the problem is that the minSdkVersion defines the APIs which you can use. If you want the minimum to be level 7, it means your program can only use things as far as API Level 7 (2.1), which means the SD install functionality will not be available.

Comment: No this is really wrong.  You don't need to set minSdkVersion to anything.  You don't need to set targetSdkVersion to anything either.  You just need to link against the version of the platform that has this attribute, which is 2.2 or later.  Just doing that won't make your app incompatible with older versions -- just set android:minSdkVersion to a lower value to say that you are still compatible with them.

Comment: But his problem is that as soon as he sets the min sdk value to 7, he is not able to achieve what he want, since he wants to use SD card, which is API level 8 (2.2). So he cannot achieve this. If he does not specify a min SDK level, his application will be 2.2 (API level 8) consequently not allowing him to achieve what he wants.

Comment: "So he cannot achieve this." -- sure he can. As Ms. Hackborn indicated, `android:minSdkVersion` has nothing to do with this. Your build target might need to be API Level 8 to avoid Eclipse grumbling, per Rich's answer. Just include `android:installLocation` in the `<manifest>` element. On older Android devices, the attribute will be ignored.

Comment: You're right. I was looking at it from the APIs perspective and wasn't aware of that attribute since I did not use this functionality before. My apologies to all.